# Split Column with fields list Python-Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, split

I heed transfroms the column `actions`,

[image]

[image]

I would like have diferent columns: `actions`, `action_type` and `Value`

[image]

The columns `actions` is type `pandas.core.series.Series`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide detailed information about your problem, a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and what you did try before posting. Some examples of inputs and expected outputs are always useful. Also, it is not a good idea to insert images to display text. Please, check [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a question for more details as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
pd.DataFrame(df.Actions.tolist())
```

Ought to do the trick.

Comment: is dont works 
TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()

Comment: I could convert to list but the list has chunks